# FadeIn e FadeOut com AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor prática na hora de mostrar avisos para o usuário, utilizando o AngularJS. Meu cenário é basicamente o seguinte: tenho uma div que representa todas as validações de CRUD, dentro do meu index.html. Em uma service "mensagens.service.js" eu possuo uma função "mostraMsgErro" que é chamada dentro de cada controller, quando este precisa mostrar a mensagem na página do usuário.

Div "chapada" no index.html:

```
<div id="mensagens" class="alert alert-danger col-md-3" hidden>
         <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a> 
         <strong style="font-size: 1.1em;">Erro ao salvar</strong><br>
         <span ng-repeat="msg in msgErro">{{msg}}<br></span>
    </div>
```

mensagens.service.js:

```
(function () {
        'use strict';

        angular
                .module('app')
                .factory('MensagensService', MensagensService);

        function MensagensService() {
            var service = {};

            service.mostraMsgErro = mostraMsgErro;

            return service;

            function mostraMsgErro() {
                $("#mensagens").fadeIn(function () {
                    window.setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#mensagens').fadeOut();
                    }, 2500);
                });
            }
        }

    })();
```

Esta abordagem está correta? Digo, a melhor maneira de implementar seria realmente esta? Caso não seja, qual a forma mais adequada para lidar com essa questão de avisos (alerts), que acredito ser trivial?

Comment: Vc poderia criar uma directiva ou component para isso

Comment: So um detalhe se quiser realmente usar o jquery para isso use dentro de $timeout do angularjs. Pode ser q algum momento vc tenha problema se nao usar o $timeout.

Comment: Por que não usa uma lib pra gerenciar os alertas? https://github.com/JanStevens/angular-growl-2

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback. 
Fabio,

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas.

Acredito que a lib angular-growl vá me atender perfeitamente!